# Firebase dynamic links Redirecting problem in android react native

Tags: react-native, firebase-dynamic-links, react-native-firebase

```
const link = await dynamicLinks().buildShortLink({
        link: 'https://invertase.io',
        domainUriPrefix: 'https://testapp.page.link',
    });
```

I am creating dynamic link using

import dynamicLinks from '@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links';

Link is creating very well with this code. but as i am clicking on the link. Link is not opening in the app. So please tell me why app is not opening when i click on the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
` ios: {
    bundleId: 'com.*****.go',
    appStoreId: '??????',
    fallbackUrl: 'http://example.com',
  },
  android: {
    packageName: 'com.*****.go',
    fallbackUrl: 'http://example.com',
  },
```

`
I guess u missing this. their site is down will have had more to say

Comment: any other thing that i can add like old version .android() @Openwell

Comment: just to confirm, are you using version 5 or 6. Also am very new to this. if it's okay I can drop a zoom link for us to debug it together.